# Test whether a directory exists or not

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I'm trying to verify that a directory exists using Fortan90. On various sites I found:

```
logical :: dir_e
inquire(file='./docs/.', exist=dir_e)

if ( dir_e ) then
  write(*,*) "dir exists!"
else
  ! workaround: it calls an extern program...
  call system('mkdir docs')
end if
```

However, `inquire` returns `False` whether or not the directory exists and if I execute this code twice, I get an error message

> cannot make dir, file already exists

If I use:

```
inquire(file='./docs/test', exist=dir_e)
```

with an existing file test, `inquire` returns `true`.

How can I check for the existence of a directory? I am using ubuntu 11.04 and the ifort compiler.

Comment: As a workaround you could also use `mkdir -p`.

Comment: Are you sure you use the inquire before the second attempt if? It works for me fine for my both compilers (Oracle Solaris Studio, Gfortran). You can also try `file='./docs'` only, that works for me also.

Comment: Here's a post from Dr. Fortran back in 2006 that background that may be of interest: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/268407.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work:

```
INQUIRE (DIRECTORY=dir, EXIST=ex [, DIRSPEC=dirspec] [, ERR=label] [, IOSTAT=i-var] )
```

I don't have ifort on this machine so I can't test it.

Addendum: The code posted originally works with gfortran. The `DIRECTORY` statement works with ifort but not with gfortran.

And in case for more information check: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/fortran/win/compiler_f/lref_for/source_files/rfinquir.htm#rfinquir

Comment: I wouldn't recommend depending on nonstandard extensions. There were too many cases, where it meant difficulties with porting to another compiler, which can be needed unexpectedly.

Comment: I of course I agree Vladimir, but the problem is that apparently the gfortran route does not work. A quick glance on the F95 standard shows that there is no behaviour for directories in the inquire statement. If I missed something (or it was addes to a later standard) let me know.

Comment: But on linux directories are just files with a directory sign on. Maybe ifort dislikes the trailing `/.`.

Comment: True. Would be nice if somebody could test this with ifort.

Comment: Works with ifort 12.0.2.137 Build 20110112. Tested just out of curiosity. Would not recommend using.

Comment: My edits do not seem to show up for whatever reason. You should correct mispelled keyword EXISTS to EXIST.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. IRO-bot what exactly did you test? The directory or the file specifier?

Comment: @Azrael3000 I tested the non-standard DIRECTORY keyword argument. I did not test the example provided by the OP.

Comment: I can verify that `inquire(directory=dir, exist=dir_e)` works for ifort 13.0.0 20120731, while `inquire(file=trim(dir)//'/.', exist=dir_e)` does not. 

If you know you're *only* using ifort (as I am), why *not* use that? In the absence of a truly portable and universal solution, why not use the solution that works for the compiler you use? 

Does anyone know what works for nagfor?

Answer (score 7):

The Fortran standard 95, 2003 and 2008 do not specify, how inquire should treat directories. From my experience under Linux, gfortran treats them as files, ifort does not. The directory statement is a proprietary feature of ifort and should therefore be avoided.

The safest would be to test for a file in the said directory.

Comment: If avoiding the `directory` feature of `ifort` was something to be avoided, we'd also want to avoid `gfortran`'s `file` feature, as both are non-portable. Of course, it'd be better yet if a future Fortran standard had some portable system utilities for such things as this.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, one checks if the directory exists so to write something in it. What I do is just create the directory. If it already exists there is no problem.

```
     CALL system("mkdir video")
     CALL chdir("video")
     CALL getcwd(path)
```

Comment: That may work somewhere, but definitely not everywhere, otherwise the question would have no point `mkdir tmp      
mkdir: cannot create directory 'tmp': File exists`

Answer (score 3):

You could use C routines to test the files :

C side (OK with ifort and gfortran on Win32 and Linux 32/64)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
#  include "dirent_windows.h"
#else
#  include <dirent.h>
#endif

void file_info(const char*filename,int*mode,int*exist,int*time){
  int k;
  struct stat buf;
  k=stat(filename,&buf);
  if(k != 0) {
    *mode=0;
    *exist=0;
    *time=0;
  }else{
    *mode=buf.st_mode;
    if(*mode == 0) *exist=0; else *exist=1;
    *time=buf.st_mtime;
  }
}
```

Fortran side :

```
MODULE file

  USE iso_c_binding

  INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE file_info(filename,mode,exist,time) BIND(C,name="file_info")
      USE iso_c_binding
      CHARACTER(kind=C_CHAR),INTENT(in) :: filename(*)
      INTEGER(C_INT),INTENT(out) :: mode,exist,time
    END SUBROUTINE
  END INTERFACE

END MODULE
```

How to use in a Fortran routine :

```
..
use file
use iso_c_binding
...
integer(c_int) :: mode,exist,time
...
call file_info("./docs"//char(0),mode,exist,time)
```

Advantage : it works for any kind of file  and  provides additional pieces of information like the mode (read/write/execute permission) and the creation time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a subroutine I use often -- it uses the conditional you asked about:

```
subroutine create_directory( newDirPath )
    ! Author:  Jess Vriesema
    ! Date:    Spring 2011
    ! Purpose: Creates a directory at ./newDirPath

    implicit none

    character(len=*), intent(in) :: newDirPath
    character(len=256)           :: mkdirCmd
    logical                      :: dirExists

    ! Check if the directory exists first
!   inquire( file=trim(newDirPath)//'/.', exist=dirExists )  ! Works with gfortran, but not ifort
    inquire( directory=newDirPath, exist=dirExists )         ! Works with ifort, but not gfortran


    if (dirExists) then
!      write (*,*) "Directory already exists: '"//trim(newDirPath)//"'"
    else
        mkdirCmd = 'mkdir -p '//trim(newDirPath)
        write(*,'(a)') "Creating new directory: '"//trim(mkdirCmd)//"'"
        call system( mkdirCmd )
    endif
end subroutine create_directory
```

Depending on which compiler you use, you'll have to decide which of those conditionals is right for you.

Unfortunately, I do not have access to `nagfor` and don't know how it treats directories.

Comment: thanks, this one works for me (gfortran sample code)

Answer (score 1):

Another non-portable solution is to let the shell (Bash, in this case) do the work:

```
call system('[[ ! -e docs ]] && mkdir docs')
```

Comment: This creates a directory. How do you get from this if a directory exists if you don't need to be created? How is this better than just `mkdir -p`?

Comment: I understood the OP's question/example to be that he wanted to create a directory. You are right,  `mkdir -p` is nearly equivalent to this explicit test. One difference is that if `docs` exists as a regular file, this method doesn't throw an error message. That may or may not be advantageous.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you want a compiler independent way of doing this, you can try to open a small file within the directory. The open statement allows for the code to jump to a particular line (specified by err=) if the open statement fails:

```
! Tests whether the directory exists
subroutine checkdir(dir)
       implicit none
       character(len=*), intent(in) :: dir
       integer :: unitno

       ! Test whether the directory exists
       open(newunit=unitno,file=trim(dir)//'deleteme.txt',status='replace',err=1234)
       close (unitno)
       return

       ! If doesn't exist, end gracefully
1234   write(*,*) 'Data directory, '//trim(dir)//' does not exist or could not write there!'
       STOP

end subroutine
```

Note that this is not foolproof, as it is assumed "dir" has the trailing "/" or "\" depending on the OS being used.

Comment: How do you tell the difference between the directory not existing and not being able to delete/create the file?

Comment: This code does not, hence the error code says does not exist or could not write there. I don't know of a way to tell the difference.