# Opening folder with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
Program Write_in_folder

Implicit none

Integer::Num_Ber
Integer,parameter::Le=367
Character(Le)::Output
Character(Le),parameter::fmt_1='("Result\Output_",i0,".txt")'
Character(Le),parameter::fmt_2='(2x,i0)'
Character(Le),parameter::fmt_3='mkdir Result'

Write(*,*)"Enter the number:"
Read(*,*)Num_Ber

Write(Output,trim(adjustl(fmt_1)))Num_Ber

Call execute_command_line(trim(adjustl(fmt_3)))

Open(Unit=1,File=trim(adjustl(Output)),Status='Unknown')

     Write(1,trim(adjustl(fmt_2)))Num_Ber

Close(Unit=1,Status='Keep') 

Stop
End Program Write_in_folder
```

I want to open folder with name: `Result_Num_Ber`

Which solution is good?

How to check whether that folder with that was name already opened? If it was there is no need for a execution this sequence of code.

Comment: Use [tag:fortran]. You are programming in a language called Fortran. Why to restrict your audence only to the few people who follow the [tag:gfortran] tag?

Comment: Is there any problem with your code? Did it do what you wanted to do? Actually, what do you mean by *"opening a folder"*? Moving to a directory? Opening a file?

Comment: Your source cannot be compiled. Did you encounter any error messages? You should show us the error messages. The `execute_command_line` is completely wrong.

Comment: numerous syntax issues aside you appear to be making a directory named `Resultn` then trying to open a file `Result/output_n` (i.e. not in the directory you just created.    )   As a total aside all of those `adjustl`'s do nothing but clutter the code.

Comment: you may find some of this useful https://stackoverflow.com/q/9522933/1004168

Comment: INQUIRE(... EXIST=) may be useful. Is there is an equivalent to Intel's GETINFOQQ in gfortran?

Comment: @Holmz: If you're thinking of GETFILEINFOQQ (I couldn't find any info about anything called GETINFOQQ), then I suppose the rough GFortran equivalent would be STAT: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/STAT.html

Comment: My ability to recall is not good, as I was using GETFILEINFOQQ earlier in the day. STAT looks useful too.

Comment: There is no problem with code. This code can create directory and in that directory a .txt file with name, for example, Result_25.
I want to open directory, for example, with name Result_25 and I want to make checking, in every future attempt, was the directory with that name alredy opened.

Comment: To repeat Vladimir F's earlier question, what do you mean by "opening a directory"?  One doesn't need to open a directory to access the files under it.

Comment: For example, I want to create, with tis code, directory Result_25 in location: C:\Something.
In the future, for example, if the input from keyboard is 25, I want fom code to make checking is that directory alredy created in the past and if was just make Result_25.txt file in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

"How to check whether that folder with that was name already opened? If it was there is no need for a execution this sequence of code."

I like using INQUIRE for both directories and for files.

```
CHARACTER(LEN=80)  :: Base_Name
CHARACTER(LEN=80)  :: SomeDirectory
CHARACTER(LEN=256) :: Full_Name
INTEGER            :: Len_SomeDirectory
LOGICAL            :: Existentialism

!....
SomeDirectory = '/data/2017'
Len_SomeDirectory = LEN_TRIM(SomeDirectory)
!...
INQUIRE(DIR=SomeDirectory, EXIST=Existentialism)
IF(Existentialism) THEN
  Full_name = SomeDirectory(1: Len_SomeDirectory) // '/' //   Base_Name(1:LEN_TRIM(Base_Name))
ELSE
  ! Maybe create some directory...
ENDIF
! etc
```

Then STAT or GETFILEINFOQQ can give insight into whether you have write permission.

Probably easiest/safest to chuck and error if there is no directory... and then create the directory manually and rerun the program.

And the same story of "what to do" if the directory or file does not have write permission... "Chuck and error and regroup."

Comment: Which version of gfortran is required for support of the `dir=` specifier to `inquire`?

Comment: Whether a directory exist is already covered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522933/test-whether-a-directory-exists-or-not  Whether it is "opened"? I have no idea what the OP means by opened directory,

Comment: @VladimirF: In the POSIX world at least, you can "open a directory" with opendir() to get a "directory stream" that you can use to iterate over all directory entries with. Also, you can open() a directory giving you a directory file descriptor that you can use to e.g. open files relative to that directory fd with openat(). That being said, I know of no Fortran compiler that exposes these operations as Fortran IO units somehow, and secondly, the OP appears novice enough that (s)he most likely has no idea about any of this anyway.

Comment: Thanks @francescalus - I am guessing that "INQUIRE(DIR=...)" is outside of the standard, and hence is not in gfortran. I have been spoiled and become dependent upon !DEC$ and other extensions.